# upload image to server 64byteString

Tags: android, image, upload

I want to upload image to server and this is the request params

- ImageName string
- ImageFile string($binary)
- ImageSrc string

when i select image i get all three i show in logcat
[image of all three request params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGnmg.png)
And when i hit the API the response is 400 i think this thing is achievable with retrofit boundary
[after hit api and response is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwJuT.png)
i am using this function to uploadimage
[firstly i tried this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1ORl.png)
And then change to this
[try second method to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnUsR.png) 
but response still error 400

I want to convert this request to multipartbody to acheive boundaries or send request successfully
this is api call interface

```
  @Multipart
    @POST("Image/UploadImage")
    Call<PersonalResponse> uploadImage(@Header("Authorization") String header, @Header("X-Requested-With") String secondHeader, @Part MultipartBody.Part filePart, @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> requestBodyMap);
```

and this is request:

```
 public void uploadImage(String token, MultipartBody.Part body, Map<String, RequestBody> requestBodyMap, CustomCallback<PersonalResponse> callback) {
        Call<PersonalResponse> call = webServices.uploadImage("Bearer " + token, "multipart/form-data", body, requestBodyMap);
        call.enqueue(callback);
```